# How to use php array echo

Tags: php, arrays, echo

How to use PHP array echo?

I don't know how to echo an array.

If array data is flow..

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [0] => red [1] => blue) 
  [1] => Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 105 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [0] => AB [1] => AC ) 
)
```

I want to echo next by..

```
red/100/AB

red/105/AB

red/100/AC

red/105/AC

blue/100/AB

blue/105/AB

blue/100/AC

blue/105/AC

..
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have attempted to do already? The site is intended to help you overcome the problems you have found with your attempts.

Comment: I think you better go and read about php [loop][1] and [array][2] first.


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
  [2]: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2):

```
    for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($arr) ; $i++ ){
       echo $arr[0][$i]."/".$arr[1][$i]."/".$arr[2][$i] ."<br/>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$any_array = array('var1'=>'data1','var2'=>'data2',etc);

print_r($any_array);
```

of if you want it formatted in an html page

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($any_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 *   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => red [1] => blue) [1] => Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 105 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => AB [1] => AC ) )
 *
 */
public function test(){

    $arr = [['red', 'blue'],[100, 105],['AB', 'AC']];


    foreach($arr[0] as $v){

        foreach($arr[1] as $v2){

            foreach($arr[2] as $v3){
                echo $v.'/'.$v2.'/'.$v3;
                echo '<br/>';
            }

        }

    }

}
```

//have a try